# Separate list of objects in Python

Tags: python, list, object

I need to separate a list of objects in Python but I don't know how to do and don't found the solution.

My list is 244 cells of data like that :

```
{'x':-9.717017,'y':-14.0228567,'z':145.401215}
```

and I want, as a result, 3 lists with all the 'x', all the 'y' and all the 'z'.
The original list is express as :

```
['{'x':-9.717017,'y':-14.0228567,'z':145.401215}', ... , '{'x':-6.44751644,'y':-65.20397,'z':-67.7079239}'].
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not hard.  `x = [d['x'] for d in data]`.

Comment: Do you really have quotes around each dictionary in the original list?

Comment: I already try this but there is quotation mark at each cell so it return an error message : TypeError: string indices must be integers. Not just next to the x, y and z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the list, and call `ast.literal_eval()` to convert each string to a dictionary. Then append each item in the dictionary to the appropriate list.

```
import ast

x_list = []
y_list = []
z_list = []
for item in data:
    d = ast.literal_eval(item)
    x_list.append(d['x'])
    y_list.append(d['y'])
    z_list.append(d['z'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the 'x', 'y', 'z' components while iterating over your list of `dict()` elements.

E.g.,

```
data = [{'x':-9.717017,'y':-14.0228567,'z':145.401215}, {'x':-9.717017,'y':-14.0228567,'z':145.401215}]

x = [d['x'] for d in data]
y = [d['y'] for d in data]
z = [d['z'] for d in data]
```

This should return the individual lists in x, y, and z respectively.

Comment: There is quotation mark at each cell and this is my big difficulty. I try your code but it doesn't work, sadly.

Comment: In OP's data, each list item is actually wrapped with `'`, thus they are strings so cannot treat them like dicts.

Comment: Oh, seems like I missed those parts.